# Scala split a 2 words which aren't seperated

Tags: scala, text, data-preprocessing

I have a corpus with words like, `applefruit` which isn't separated by any separator which I would like to do. As this can be a non-linear problem. I would like to pass a custom dictionary to split only when a word from the dictionary is a substring of a word in the corpus.

if my dictionary has only `apple`  and 3 words in corpus `aaplefruit`, `applebananafruit`, `bananafruit`. The output should look like  `apple , fruit` `apple, bananafruit`, `bananafruit`.

Notice I am not splitting `bananafruit`, the goal is to make the process faster by just splitting on the text provided in the dictionary. I am using scala 2.x.

Comment: Could you describe some logic aim to be implemented, please ? Because I'm not really following why expected output is: `apple , fruit apple, bananafruit, bananafruit` - would you like to split each token by `apple` world or remove it as a prefix? Or anything else?

Comment: @IvanKurchenko I have some lines which I am breaking into words for further analysis, but as text is not clean I am getting words like `badapple` i.e. 2 words joined, I was hoping to get something to break this one into 2. which obviously will help whatever analysis I will do on word level.

Reason I wanted to pass a dictionary of words to look is as the data size is large it can reduce run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with split:

```
scala> "foobarfoobazfoofoobatbat".split("(?<=foo)|(?=foo)")
res27: Array[String] = Array(foo, bar, foo, baz, foo, foo, batbat)
```

Or if your dictionary (and/or strings to split) has more than one word ...

```
   val rx = wordList.map { w => s"(?<=$w)|(?=$w)" }.mkString("|")
   val result: List[String] = toSplit.flatMap(_.split(rx))
```

Comment: yeah that's one of the issue I will have a large dictionary. so can take quite a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regex find and replace on the following pattern:

```regex
(?=apple)|(?<=apple)
```

and then replace with comma surrounded by spaces on both sides.  We could try:

```scala
val input = "bananaapplefruit"
val output = input.replaceAll("(?=apple)|(?<=apple)", " , ")
println(output)  // banana , apple , fruit
```